# Create HttpServer with public ipv4 address

Tags: java, httpserver, ipv4

I'm setting up a HttpServer via com.sun.net.httpserver.
I want to be able to reach the server via my public ipv4 address.

I already managed to get it working with `localhost`.

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
server.createContext("/", Main::server.setExecutor(null);
server.start();
```

I tried it with

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("83.180.65.342");
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(ip, 8080), 0);
```

But it returns

```
java.ne.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
```

Comment: Is something else listening on that port?

Comment: @Steve Smith no, even if i try other ports it gives the same output

Comment: are you sure this is the correct IP? why aren't you using `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`?

Comment: @matanper That is actually working. I thought i have to use my public ipv4 address but doesn't look like it. Thank you!

Comment: @matanper But how do I know which IP address it's bound to, such that I can make API calls on my front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing this on a local development machine while your public machine is actually a distinct machine elsewhere ?  That obviously won't work.

If that is the problem, make your IP address a configurable property in the installation instead of hardcoding it.  Or else use getLocalHost() (and configure your machines' networking and DNS options properly so that it won't return 127.0.0.1).

Comment: But how do I know which IP address it's bound to, such that I can make API calls on my front end?